# Add web application support in an Intellij module

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications

According to this article:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-application-support.html

I should be able to see 'web application' in the list of supported frameworks but this is not the case.

I am using Intellij 2016.3 Utlimate, and the module is a simple maven module.

Comment: I only have IJ 14 so I'm not sure how different the user interfaces are. Nonetheless, if you already have created the module, go to `File -> Project structure`, select `Facets` then click on the green plus icon to add a new one, and select `Web`. Alternatively, please descrive what you've done so far, and try including some screenshots so we can better understand the problem

Comment: Do you have the plugin enabled?